# Post nested params (hash) using HTTPClient

Tags: ruby

I needed a to have a multipart http post from one app to another that included a file attachment and a nested params hash.  I tried using `HTTPClient` which worked for the file attachment, however I could not get params to send in a nested format.

```
data_params = Hash.new
data_params[:params] = Hash.new
data_params[:params][:f] = Hash.new
data_params[:params][:d] = Hash.new
data_params[:params][:d][:name] = "Mich"
data_params[:params][:d][:city] = "Ostin"
data_params[:params][:f][:event] = "Sundance"

http_client = HTTPClient.new
body = data_params[:params]
response = http_client.post('http://localhost:3030/receiver/receive_test_data/', body)
```

with the receiver app seeing the params as `{"d"=>"nameMichcityOstin","f"=>"eventSundance"}` (with the hash collapsed into strings on the nested level)

I wonder if this is a limitation on http posts or am I simply doing something wrong.  I have worked with JSON before, which I know supports a nested structure, but there I have no idea how to add file attachments.  I appreciate any suggestions or alternative methods that would comply with 'best practices' on doing something like this.

Answer (score 4):

If using Rails:

```
> {:a=>53,:b=>{:c=>7}}.to_query 
=> "a=53&b[c]=7"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/to_query

Comment: when I try "x = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params.to_query)" I get an error "undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007fa8e40d8b28>". How can I use this on a nested params hash?

Comment: the method post_form is meant to take an hash and not the query string.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I switched to using the `.post` method and worked. `http.post(uri.path, params.to_query)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which `HTTPClient` library you're using so I haven't been able to try this, but what if you use keys like this

```
data_params[:params]['d[name]'] = "Mich"
data_params[:params]['d[city]'] = "Ostin"
```

i.e. `data_params[:params]` is just a one level hash.

and then the receiving application will unpack this into the nested hash that you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  It would be nice to have something that could take in a hash of arbitrary depth and post it.  I suppose it would have to be something like an XML post and a separate file post.