# Ruby/Rails Net::HTTP.post_form nested hash items html escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Example I am doing this in rails console:

```
params = {"type"=>["raka"], "fields"=>["exhb_0", "exh0_1", "t_g_a", "hp_1", "s1", "overflade_0", "t2", "t3", "t4"], "railing"=>["A-3"], "wood"=>["wood_6"], "railing_m"=>"0", "order"=>{"sving"=>"right", "size"=>{"ground"=>"123", "floor"=>"6", "a"=>"6", "d"=>"6"}, "comments"=>{"step_2"=>"", "step_3"=>"", "step_4"=>""}, "railing"=>{"1"=>"1", "2"=>"1"}, "railing_m"=>{"1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>"12"}, "hul"=>{"l"=>"123", "b"=>"123"}, "name"=>"qwed", "email"=>"mail@example.com", "phone"=>"13123", "street"=>"iuuj", "city"=>"ui", "postnr"=>"213"}}

x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/download.pdf'), params)
```

In my Rails console I can see the HTTP post request:

```
Started POST "/download.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-15 16:25:36 +0200
Processing by PublicController#show_pdf as */*
  Parameters: {"type"=>"raka", "fields"=>"t4", "railing"=>"A-3", "wood"=>"wood_6
", "railing_m"=>"0", "order"=>"{\"sving\"=>\"right\", \"size\"=>{\"ground\"=>\"1
23\", \"floor\"=>\"6\", \"a\"=>\"6\", \"d\"=>\"6\"}, \"comments\"=>{\"step_2\"=>
\"\", \"step_3\"=>\"\", \"step_4\"=>\"\"}, \"railing\"=>{\"1\"=>\"1\", \"2\"=>\"
1\"}, \"railing_m\"=>{\"1\"=>\"\", \"2\"=>\"\", \"3\"=>\"\", \"4\"=>\"12\"}, \"h
ul\"=>{\"l\"=>\"123\", \"b\"=>\"123\"}, \"name\"=>\"qwed\", \"email\"=>\"mail@example.com\", \"phone\"=>\"13123\", \"street\"=>\"iuuj\", \"city\"=>\"ui\", \"postn
r\"=>\"213\"}"}
```

The problem is that all the nested http params are HTML escaped. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Please describe the problem? If escaping of nested params is a problem, what problem are you facing? Or to put it simply, why do you want to get rid of the escaping?

Comment: The problem is that the nested params are HTML escaped..

Comment: So? Is it affecting your program logic in anyways?

Comment: yes http://pastie.org/private/jihu4ky7kgnt01k3p4ozg#, I cannot use the ruby style sympol for the paremeters if they are escaped..

Comment: the parameter fields is also changed it is no longer an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails world, `params` is not a regular Hash object that Ruby provides out of the box. In fact its a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) that is provided by Rails that allows the keys to be accessed, as a symbol or as a string.

```
irb(main):001:0>params = {"type"=>["raka"], "fields"=>["exhb_0", "exh0_1", "t_g_a", "hp_1", "s1", "overflade_0", "t2", "t3", "t4"], "railing"=>["A-3"], "wood"=>["wood_6"], "railing_m"=>"0", "order"=>{"sving"=>"right", "size"=>{"ground"=>"123", "floor"=>"6", "a"=>"6", "d"=>"6"}, "comments"=>{"step_2"=>"", "step_3"=>"", "step_4"=>""}, "railing"=>{"1"=>"1", "2"=>"1"}, "railing_m"=>{"1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>"12"}, "hul"=>{"l"=>"123", "b"=>"123"}, "name"=>"qwed", "email"=>"mail@example.com", "phone"=>"13123", "street"=>"iuuj", "city"=>"ui", "postnr"=>"213"}}
irb(main):002:0>params.class
=> Hash
irb(main):003:0>params[:fields]
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>params = params.with_indifferent_access
irb(main):005:0>params.class
=> ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
irb(main):006:0>params[:fields]
=> ["exhb_0", "exh0_1", "t_g_a", "hp_1", "s1", "overflade_0", "t2", "t3", "t4"]
```

Comment: Got my problem solved by using the anwser by Hallucynogenyc in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387760/rails-escaping-backslashes-in-params-causing-havoc

Comment: Great, so long as you found the answer to your problem :)

Answer (score 5):

The `.post_form` method accepts strings, so it causes this escaping problem when passed a nested hash.  I had this same problem and switched to the `.post` method, and solved it.

```
require "net/http"
uri = URI('http://www.yoururl.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
response = http.post(uri.path, params.to_query)
```

Note also the use of the `.to_query` method of converting a hash to a string. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504300/post-nested-params-hash-using-httpclient/5182785#comment40669680_5182785)